# in my JS game, the ball not going smooth angled. always making curve move. how can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making html+js game. In my game ball comes from on right with that code

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.loop.length; i++){
            let ballNow = this.loop[i];
            ballNow.x -= ballNow.speed;
```

and if character.x == ball.x, ball goes through. this is not problem.
but I try to give an angle to ball. like that

```
const dif = ball.loop[i].x - footballer.x - footballer.width/2;
ballNow.x += dif;
```

ball making curve. because every frame reference the ballNow.x and refresh himself i guess. For example when I wrote ballNow.x += 2, the ball going like what I want.

I tried 2 solutions. I think about this is reference problem and I tried object.assign and object.create methods. But always "dif" increased and ball made curve.

Ball going like this and what i want
[image]

What should I write for the ball going angled without curve move?

Note: I shouldn't use any library.

Comment: It feels like a mathematical problem with how you increment the ball's `x` coordinate. Instead of increasing it linearly (i.e. constant increment), you seem to be adding a variable whose value is not constant, which causes a larger and larger delta in the x coordinate.

Comment: yes delta always changing. i tried to keep value constant with clone methods but it doesnt work.